# Why am I having such a problem editing the font size?

Tags: html, font-size

I can't get it any bigger I have tried a few html variations... I want it HUGE... I know this is basic but I've tried a few things

http://www.drillavailable.neighborrow.com/

```
<div style="text-align: center;"><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<font size="100">NO:(</font>
<br><br>no one within 3 miles of your location has listed their drill yet, be 
<a href="http://u.neighborrow.com/items/create/">the first!</a><br></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `<font size="100">NO:(</font>` with `<span style="font-size:100pt;">NO:(</span>`

Answer (score 5):

Use CSS:

```
<span style="font-size: 100px">NO:(</span>
```

The number of the `font` tags size attribute is an alias and therefore limited:
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#propdef-font-size

> Possible values are:
>   [ xx-small | x-small | small | medium | large | x-large | xx-large ]

Which map from `1` to `7`.

Answer (score 2):

Per W3c, the font size specifier can only be between 1-7. You may try adding `style="font-size:100px;"` and use pixels though.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_font_size.asp for reference

Answer (score 2):

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <span style="font-size:100pt;display:block">NO!</span>
    no one within 3 miles of your location has listed their drill yet, be 
    <a href="http://u.neighborrow.com/items/create/">the first!</a>
</div>
```

Preview @ [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rksu7/)

Answer (score 1):

In your `<div>` you can add `style="font-size:100px"` to change the font size of the text inside of that element.